# Kqemu Installation on Fedora 13

Tags: virtualization, qemu, kvm

Can anyone tell me how to install kqemu on Fedora 13 host machine. I saw somewhere that Kqemu is not supported by Fedora 13, is that true???

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QEMU#Accelerator